# how to check if you liked fan page with php without app access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

How to check if you liked fan page with php without app access token? I need to check if you liked fan page to know if that i will hide iframe of page like, to not display it all times while users open my site.

Is it possible? I need to check it with php with get content or curl.

```
<iframe id="closebox3" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/rohelhayatt&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=60&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=31" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant. You can either implement an idempotent "like" button which will always send a like request(and another button to unlike) or use javascript sdk to get the iframe on your site.
Use the Graph API to find what data you can access. 
Replace 'me' with the post you would like to 'like' and go from there.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me

Update
You can only like posts, pictures and such. Not pages and other stuff in the top level of th graph. You need Javascript sdk or log into facebook. 
Sorry for the confusion, hope this helps!

Comment: How to make like and unlike ???